# AJAX response match any status

Tags: ajax, response

I have the following code:

```
    $.ajax(
        {
            url:        "control/" + id + ".php",
            data:       $("auth-form").serialize(),
            statusCode:
            {
                200: function( response )
                {

                },
                401: function( response )
                {

                },

                401: function( response )
                {

                },
            }
        }
    );
```

I need to set callback to 'any' status, whether it's 200 or 404 I need it to trigger the same callback function, something like this:

```
            $.ajax(
        {
            url:        "control/" + id + ".php",
            data:       $("auth-form").serialize(),
            response = function( r )
            {
                alert('got ' + r.status);
            }
        }
    );
```

Closest solution I found was using success/fail, but I need to combine them somehow. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `complete`:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "control/" + id + ".php",
        data: $("auth-form").serialize(),
        complete: function( r ) {
            alert('got ' + r.status);
        }
    }
);
```